# How to publish excel VSTO for different frameworks

Tags: c#, .net, excel, visual-studio, vsto

I am very new  to c# , I have now created my first excel VSTO which calculates some custom values for the data columns in the active sheet. Now I have to publish the same and get it installed in 5 to 6 PC , the VSTO I have created is having .Netframework 4.8 and tested in Microsoft excel for Microsoft 365 MSO 32-bit.

But the target systems are having excel 2013,2010 & 2007 and lower version of framework.

How to publish this VSTO which can support these requirements ?please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You can try two possibilities:

1. Publish in the lowest available version of the framework.
2. Update the framework in the clients PC.